# Google Tools Dynamic Drop-downs

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets

I'd like to be able to use dynamic drop downs in my Google Sheets? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the file provided and:

1. Copy three tabs (sheets: "Entry", "District", Subdistrict") directly into to workbook.
2. Integrate tab Entry with the rest of the primary sheet (data entry). Best option is to place the the geo columns ("Governorate", "District", "Subdistrict") at the far right of the sheet.
3. Protect and hide sheets "District" and "Subdistrict".
4. In the primary sheet protect and hide columns D-CA. The columns name headings may change.